# android how to inflate one view defined in a layout file (not whole file)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

android how to inflate one view defined in a layout file (not whole file)? For example,

```
<anyLayout ...>

    <Button ... />
    <TextView ... />

    <!-- many many more -->

</anyLayout>
```

Different view components(e.g. Button, TextView) will be created (inflated) depending on different conditions. Is there a way to inflate one component in the layout file instead of whole file?

Each component can be defined in its own layout file. There are many. Can they put into one layout file and inflated separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can they put into one layout file and inflated separately?

No. When you inflate a layout resource, you are inflating everything inside that file.

> Different view components(e.g. Button, TextView) will be created (inflated) depending on different conditions.

It sounds like you might be able to achieve what you want by using [`ViewStub` tags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub).

To do this, you would create your main layout file as normal. However, anywhere you want to have dynamic content, you add a `<ViewStub>` tag. Then, in Java/Kotlin, after you inflate your main layout, you can inflate different views into the ViewStub.

- `main_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

- `button.xml`

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLICK ME">
```

- `text.xml`

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Can't click me">
```

- `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    ViewStub stub = findViewById(R.id.stub);

    if (isUseButton) {
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.button);
    } else {
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.text);
    }

    stub.inflate();
}
```